# Initialization methods for PFObject Subclass Objects that are Generated by Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, subclass, pfobject

This is tagged with `iOS`, but I'm sure it could be useful for the other Parse SDKs as well. As you may know, Parse added the ability to create native `PFObject` subclasses to the `iOS` SDK not too long ago. This is a great addition for a number of reasons. Firstly, it allows compiler to check your code by creating dynamic properties for object attributes:

`myObject[@"myAttribute"]` is converted to `myObject.myAttribute`

Secondly, and more important to this question, custom subclasses can have added functionality. For example, say I have created an alarm app that stores `Alarm` objects on the Parse cloud. In my custom subclass, I can override the `+ (instancetype)object`, `- (void)saveEventually`, and `- (void)deleteEventually` methods so that the `alarm` object can schedule/update/remove a `UILocalNotification` for itself upon creation, modification, or deletion.

Here's where things get complicated and my actual question comes in. Say a user creates an alarm on one device (which uploads it to the cloud), and then syncs it automatically to another device. The second device obviously updates it's contents in the background with `PFQuery`'s `- (BFTask *)findObjectsInBackground` and then calls `- (BFTask *)fetchIfNecessaryInBackground` on each object to ensure that all of its substance is on the device. My question is: What method(s), if any, gets called when a `PFObject` subclass is found/fetched from the Parse cloud database? For that matter, what about objects initialized from the local datastore?

Like I mentioned, overriding various methods works perfectly for objects that are created and managed on the device, but I am baffled as to how one would run custom code from within a new object that just arrived in memory from the local or remote datastore. Any thoughts or suggestions on how to handle this would be much appreciated. The Parse documentation does not cover such a case, so it may not even be best practice, but it seems to me that it should be. Anyway, thank you for your time and your insights.

Answer (score 0):

As for most subclasses of `NSObject`, the way to go is probably to override the `-init` method.

However, as you mentioned in your last paragraph, such practice is undocumented and you should probably avoid it. The way `PFObjects` work makes it possible to have multiple instances of the same object in memory (multiple `PFObjects` with the same `objectId`). And you do not control when or why these objects are created, so relying on code executed when they are initialized is probably a bad idea. If you have been using Core Data, note that Parse really handles things in a different way, so the best practices are different.

For example, I'm not saying this is the case, but what if a copy of each object is created before it is saved ? Of what if the object is created twice when making a query with the 'cache then network' policy ? Even if you make it work, you would still end up with something that could break with every update of the Framework.

I think you should bundle you initialization code in a method of your own that you would call yourself on objects when you receive them from a query or from the local datastore. Overriding is a good design and practice in object oriented programming, but there are some exceptions and I think this is one of them.